# Adding filter expression in collection mapping rules XDCR with Java client

Tags: java, couchbase, xdcr

I am integrating XDCR via JAVA Sdk. If I need to setup filter expression per collection mapping rule how to do in java?
say collection mapping rule 1 has one filter expression,
collection mapping rule 2 has some other filter expression and so on.

Comment: The Couchbase Java SDK does not have an API for managing XDCR.

One option is to use the [SDK's HTTP client](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-jvm-clients/blob/d88c840977d6f8d67fc1dc5bec5a7510341aa82c/java-client/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/java/http/CouchbaseHttpClient.java#L25-L63) to invoke the [XDCR HTTP API](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/rest-api/rest-xdcr-intro.html) yourself.

Comment: Thanks for reply. with XDCR HTTP API if we have collection mapping rules can we add filter expression per collection mapping rule ? if yes what will be the sample code. say if sourcecollection11->targetcollection1 should be replicated with filter expression 1. sourcecollection2->targetcollection2 should be replicated with filter expression 2 and so one

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST API to configure collection mappings: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/rest-api/rest-xdcr-adv-settings.html (look for `calMappingRules`)